# Laravel queues - freeing up memory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.5

Laravel [5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker) mention that:

> Daemon queue workers do not "reboot" the framework before processing each job. Therefore, you should free any heavy resources after each job completes. For example, if you are doing image manipulation with the GD library, you should *free the memory* with `imagedestroy` when you are done.

Where exactly should I free up the memory? Within the `handle` method of the job itself?
At this point, I need to use queues just to send emails and push data to Zapier/IFTTT. Should I even worry about freeing up the memory for such uses?

Comment: I would think this is only an issue for resources that are not garbage collected like (perhaps) file handles and/or sockets?

Comment: You are probably right on that. The documentation doesn't mention when and where to use it exactly - only that it is something that you may need to do. Queues are a new thing to me, and I wasn't sure if I was not missing some critical part of using them, so preferred to ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably ok with just emailing and pushing some data upstream. But to answer your question, yes the end of the handle function is a good place to do any clean up after the job completes.